# How to bind bit value True or False in Kendo ui dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I want to bind a record based on the record in the database for the selected personid using kendo Ui dropdownlist. If isDisable is null then it need to bind to Please select option. However, i have issue with it. Here is the code that i have so far:

here is the table:

```
PersonId  PersonName    isDisable (bit datatype)
1         Jack          False
2         Tony          True
3         Brian         Null 

controller:
TRN_DataAccessLayer.Person data = dbPerson.GetPersonbyID(id);
ViewBag.isDisable= data.isDisable;
```

In View Razor page:

```
<input type="isDisable" id="isDisable" name="isDisable" style="width:220px; font-size:12px; align:center; font-size:11px; width:156px; length:35px;margin:1.0em 1.5em 5px -10px"/>

<script>

 var data= [
                        { text: "Yes", value: "1" },
                        { text: "No", value: "0" },

        ];

var cond = parseInt(@ViewBag.isDisable) === 0;
$("#isDisable").kendoDropDownList({

            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: data,
            index: cond ? 0 : 1,
            optionLabel: {
                text: "Please Select",
                value: "-1"
            }



        });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It just works fine, but make sure you use the latest http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/js/kendo.all.min.js

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefh/TY5vn/) for an example.

[image]

Comment: Hi Stef, THe fiddle link above is different with the screen shoot you provide above.